# Skype isnt installed, but Wampserver(2.2d) stays orange in tray

Tags: wampserver

As in subject. Im working with old laptop acer travelmate 529txv, and before installing motherboard drivers Wampserver was fine, but after installed it stays orange in tray. These drivers called "ULi_Integrated220.rar".

Comment: nobody knows why stays orange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed apache from 2.2.21 to 2.2.22 and now it work.